# How do I conditonally add wrapper in loop React?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Actually my question is about `React Native`, but i think it's similar to React.

I'm tried to create dynamic menu with loop in array like this:

[image: Content]

My question is: how do I conditionally add another `<View/>` while using `map`?

let say there's 4 value in array and I've tried to do something like this:

```
_renderMenu(){
  let menu = this.state.menu.map((el, index)=>{
    if(index==0){
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1, margin:5, borderRadius:5, backgroundColor:Color.amber_200}}/>
      )
    } else {
      //Wrap the rest with <View style={MyStyle}>
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1, margin:5, borderRadius:5, backgroundColor:Color.amber_200}}/>
      )
      //</View>
    }
  })
  return(
    <View style={{flex:1, padding:5}}>
      {menu}
    </View>
  )
}
```

My loop pattern something like this:

```
   <View style={{flex:1, margin:5, borderRadius:5, backgroundColor:Color.amber_200}}/>
   <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flex:1}}> //if index!==0 wrap the rest with this view
     <View style={{flex:1, margin:5, borderRadius:5, backgroundColor:Color.amber_200}}/>
     <View style={{flex:1, margin:5, borderRadius:5, backgroundColor:Color.amber_200}}/>
     <View style={{flex:1, margin:5, borderRadius:5, backgroundColor:Color.amber_200}}/>
   </View>
```

Is it possible to conditionally something like my case?

Comment: Can you please add your menu object (`this.state.menu`) ?

Comment: you can change `this.state.menu` with `[0,1,2,3].map(...)` @RocKhalil

Comment: but the idea is the following: in order to have a "dynamic" render mechanism, you'll need to have a good structure. Have `menu = [1, 2, 3]` is wrong, it should be something like: `menu = [ { title: 1 }, { title: 2, children: [ { title: 3 } ] } ]`. If the first one is the case, then it's a little bit wrong how you're doing it but can be also done

Comment: No need to, I misunderstood the question and now wrote an answer for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above comments, here's a solution for your problem:

First, you'll need to add `lodash` to the project to use the `_.chunck` method: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk

```
_renderMenu() {
  const menuItem = (item, index) => (
    <View key={`menu_item_${index}`} style={{ flex: 1, margin: 5, borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: Color.amber_200 }}>{item}</View>
  )
  const splitArray = _.chunk(this.state.menu.slice(1), 3)

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 5 }}>
      {menuItem(this.state.menu[0], 0)}
      {
        splitArray.map((array, index) => {
          return (
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
              {array.map((element, elementIndex) => menuItem(element, (elementIndex * index) + elementIndex + 1))}
            </View>
          )
        })
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

the `splice` will skip the specified number of elements, in our case, the first one. We will render the first menu item alone, then will render the other items.

Now for the key, i'm trying to keep it unique using the `* +` formula to generate them based on both indexes.

Comment: I've thought of that _hack_, but i need to keep the pattern whenever the value of array is more than 4, appreciated your help :)

Comment: @flix so every row should have 3 items ?

Comment: yes. if the value is 6, i have 1 item row, 3 item row, and 1 item row, 1 item row with the size of flex/3